# error: cannot find symbol and how to create and add objects to an arraylist

Tags: java, class, object, arraylist, cannot-find-symbol

I'm attempting to create objects of my Profile class and store them in an arrayList created in a ProfileCollector class I created.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class ProfileCollector
{
  private ArrayList<Profile> profileList;

  public ProfileCollector()
  {
    profileList = new ArrayList<Profile>();
    //peopleList = new ArrayList<String>();
  }
  public void addProfile(String initName, int initKcalTotal, int initProteinTotal, int initFatTotal){
    profileList.add(new Profile(initName, initKcalTotal, initProteinTotal, initFatTotal));

  }
}
```

Here is my profile class:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Profile
{
  private ArrayList<DailyIntake> nutritionalStats;
  private String name;
  private int kcalTotal;
  private int proteinTotal;
  private int fatTotal;
  //These values represent nutritional requirements


  public Profile(String initName, int initKcalTotal, int initProteinTotal, int initFatTotal)
  {
    name = initName;
    kcalTotal = initKcalTotal;
    proteinTotal = initProteinTotal;
    fatTotal = initFatTotal;
  }

  public String getName(){
    return name;
  }
  public int getKcalTotal(){
    return kcalTotal;
  }
  public int getProteinTotal(){
    return proteinTotal;
  }
  public int getFatTotal(){
    return fatTotal;
  }

}
```

Here are the parts of my main.java that are important

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    ProfileCollector profiles = new ProfileCollector();
    //theres also a line that calls to a method which calls to another method with this line: profiles.addProfile(new Profile(name, optimumCalories, optimumProteins, optimumFats));
}
```

The error message is that the variable profiles is cannot be found. My question is also if I am correctly creating objects and adding them to an ArrayList. I didn't know if creating a class was the best way to go about this, but it was the way I've partial seen before. Anything helps.

Here is the error message:

error: cannot find symbol
              profiles.addProfile(new Profile(name,
 optimumCalories, optimumProteins, optimumFats));
              ^
  symbol:   variable profiles
  location: class Main

Comment: Probably help to put in your post a direct paste of the actual error you have as it's not clear

Answer (score 2):

You can add a method in the ProfileCollector class, that accepts an Profile instance instead of 4 parameters. With this class you should be able to be able to add a new profile to your list and you should also be able to add a profile by typing in the 4 parameters, that are required to create a new Profile instance.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class ProfileCollector
{
    private ArrayList<Profile> profileList;

    public ProfileCollector()
    {
        profileList = new ArrayList<Profile>();
        //peopleList = new ArrayList<String>();
    }
    public void addProfile(String initName, int initKcalTotal, int initProteinTotal, int initFatTotal){
        profileList.add(new Profile(initName, initKcalTotal, initProteinTotal, initFatTotal));
    }

    public void addProfile(Profile profile) {
        profileList.add(profile);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need make sure to send by parameters the `profiles` variable to that function and then send it to the other function that you said it calls

```
profiles.addProfile(new Profile(name, optimumCalories, optimumProteins, optimumFats));
```

Also you are giving a variable type Profile to the addProfile ,maybe you need to send only the profile atributes

```
profiles.addProfile(name, optimumCalories, optimumProteins, optimumFats);
```

Or change the addProfile to have a Profile by parameters that is the best practice

```
public void addProfile(Profile profile) {
        profileList.add(profile);
    }
```

If this is not the answer could you add some code from that functions, if you don't want to share the code put `...`

Answer (score 0):

Both Answeres above are good.

It is a **compilation** error so **you need to learn how to interpret IDE error messages** from the compiler. 
The problem is you are calling a method signature that does not exist.

Eather define the method

`public void addProfile(Profile profile)`

or call the existiong method:

`profiles.addProfile("Profile1", 1650, 450, 350);`

use "this" to refer to own properties in an Object.

```
 public void addProfile(String initName, int initKcalTotal, int initProteinTotal, int initFatTotal){
        this.profileList.add(new Profile(initName, initKcalTotal, initProteinTotal, initFatTotal));
    }
```

Keep it up!

Comment: thanks! I was able to fix this error by adding this line inside of the main class: public static ProfileCollector profiles = new ProfileCollector();